# newbie Question : How to consume this Node.Js Api?

Tags: node.js, rest

I am following this very good tutorial : [NODE.js JSON Api](https://robkendal.co.uk/blog/how-to-build-a-restful-node-js-api-server-using-json-files/)

But I am really struggling to not understand how to use it.

I am trying to figure out how to write into my index.js route file to have the listing of content of the JSON file when visiting /users  URL :

What is strange to me is the idea to have the ROUTE into the API Code like

```
 app.get("/users", (req, res) => {
fs.readFile(dataPath, "utf8", (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  }

  res.send(JSON.parse(data));
});
```

});

Does anybody with time to help ?
thanks in advance

Comment: what is `dataPath` in your code snippet?

Comment: Open a browser and go to: http://localhost:3001/users

Comment: Hey @VenkySoorisetty thanks per contribute ...
for while the data path is HARD coded as ./data/users.json 
what is strange to me is ... should I call something to have the readFile be executed or this will happen when I reach /users ? 
I Will post the code where each FileOperation is defined

Comment: const userRoutes = (app, fs) => {
  // variables
  const dataPath = "./data/users.json";

  const readFile = (
      callback,
      returnJson = false,
      filePath = dataPath,
      encoding = "utf8"
    ) => {
      fs.readFile(filePath, encoding, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        }
        callback(returnJson ? JSON.parse(data) : data);
      });
    };

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a front application (usually with React / Vue / Angular) then make a fetch request to your api (to the route you want to get infos from)

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand the use of making REST API, usually, they are meant to connect the backend(the business logic) of the application with some sort of UI (frontend application), or feeding data to some other third-party applications.

There are different methods for making an API GET, POST, DELETE to name a few. As your example shows you are working with `GET` method you can directly hit the URL in the browser to get the response e.g. http://localhost:<PORT_WHERE_APPLICATION_RUNNING>/users.

For another kind of requests, you can use REST clients like [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) or something more sophisticated like [Postman](https://www.postman.com/).

You can learn more about REST API's [here](https://medium.com/becloudy/rest-api-101-e022b6f6ae78)